# What's the best way to rename files with the same modified date and time?

Tags: python, windows, file, rename

Path a/b/c/d where folder d has a bunch of files and folders, something like this.

- Folder E which has abc.txt, def.jpg, and ghi.pst
- Folder D also has loose files like jkl.pst, mno.jpg, pqr.txt

Path w/x/y/z where folder z has a bunch of folders named like

- a3cj85zblahblahblah
- asdfljklqwpeoriu833

Each of these folders contains a file, or files from one of the folders in path a/b/c/d.  They are the same files except they've been renamed. So the file named abc.txt from a/b/c/d/FolderE is now in any folder in the path w/x/y/z renamed as bf6241b7c8b1.txt.

I know it's the same file because I not only compared them but they also have the same modified date, type, and size.  I was thinking about using os.rename and os.walk but I don't know where to start.  I'm fairly new to Python and need to get this done ASAP in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode:

1. Find all files in locations Source and Target.
2. For each file in Source, calculate (checksum, size), and use this as a key in a dict, where the value is the filename.
3. For each file in Target, calculate (checksum, size), and look it up in the dict created previously.  If it exists, rename it.